# Is there a way to use the DBC views to find the last date and time that a database schema was altered?

Tags: teradata

I would like to find the date and time that any schema modification has taken place on a particular database.  Modifications are things like tables or columns that have been created, altered, or dropped.  It does not include any data that has been inserted, updated, or deleted.

The reason why I need this is because I am writing a .NET utility that depends heavily on the data returned from `dbc.tables`, `dbc.columns`, and `dbc.indices`.  Since querying these views can be a very expensive operation, I want to read it all into custom business objects and then serialize the objects to an XML file stored on disk.  This way, I can just deserialize the data when I need it unless the database's current_timestamp is greater than or equal to the datetime of the last schema change, at which point I'll refresh the local XML file with the updated schema.

Answer (score 2):

`LastAlterTimestamp` - If it is equal to `CreateTimestamp` then object has not been modified since being created or replaced. It is updated when an attribute specific to that data dictionary object was updated.

For example, DBC.Databases.LastAlterTimestamp is not update when a child object (table, view, macro, stored procedure, function, etc.) is added, removed, or altered. It is updated in situations such as when the password, default role, profile, or account is changed.

Comment: I just confirmed that adding tables and altering columns and even indices changed the max(LastAlterTimestamp).  However, dropping a table appears to affect the aggregation by returning the LastAlterTimestamp value of the object with the next highest LastAlterTimestamp of the table that was just dropped.  I checked the LastAlterTimestamp of dbc.databases, but it does not seem to change when a table is dropped.  Any ideas?

Comment: I suppose I could store the LastAlterTimestamp to a file and then check if that value has changed as opposed to doing a greater than/equal to check.  Still, I'd like to know why the LastAlterTimestamp is affected this way.

Comment: Added additional clarification to the scope of LastAlterTimestamp.

Comment: Thanks for that.  What are your comments on my response regarding the aggregation of the LastAlterTimestamp value of dbc.tables when a table is dropped?

Comment: DBC.Databases.LastAlterTimestamp will not change when you drop a table. The MAX(DBC.TVM.LastAlterTimestamp) can change when you drop a table. When you drop a table the row in DBC.TVM is removed. Therefore, if the table dropped was the last altered you will have a new last altered table.